# Cannot return bool from function

Tags: c, function, boolean

This is the piece of code in base C:

```
static bool is_ascii_value_of_digit(char ascii_value){

    if((ascii_value<40)&&(ascii_value >= 30)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The avr studio gcc compiler is giving me error :

> ../calculator.h:4: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'is_ascii_value_of_digit'

Similar errors are also evident in other functions.  I do not know why this is happening. Spent an hour figuring out why and finally gave up.  As far as I have seen online, my syntax is not the problem.  Probably something that I am overlooking.

Question RESOLVED !

Thank you very much for your quick help as it saved me a lot of time.  I was under the assumption that bool is a keyword in c.

Comment: bool is not a keyword unless you are using C99. Try either replacing bool with int and return 1/0 respectively.

Comment: @Yuushi: `bool` is not a keyword in C99 either (or in C11).  It's undefined if you don't have `#include <stdbool.h>`, and if you do it's a macro that expands to `_Bool`, which *is* a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have just forgotten to `#include <stdbool.h>`.

However, you have a mismatch between name and behaviour of your function,

```
if((ascii_value<40)&&(ascii_value >= 30))
```

the decimal digits, 0-9, occupy the places 48-57 in the ASCII table, that's hexadecimal `0x30`-`0x39`, so to match the name, you should test

```
if (ascii_value < 0x3A && ascii_value >= 0x30)
```

Comment: or just `return isdigit(ascii_value)` :)

Comment: Yeah :D But I was under the impression do-it-yourself was the point here.

Comment: Clearer: `if (ascii_value >= '0' && ascii_value <= '9')` (assuming you're trying to do this without `isdigit()`).

Comment: @tomlogic: That's not only clearer, it's more portable (in EBCDIC, `'0` .. `'9'` are `0xF0` .. `0xF9`.  (C does guarantee that the values are contiguous, a guarantee it doesn't make for letters.)

Answer (score 3):

C does not have `bool` type, neither `true` or `false`. Use `int` and `0`/`1` values instead.

Comment: It does since 1999, all you need is `<stdbool.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports, at least partially, the C99 standard (or C11, but that's not yet likely), add

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

to the top of your source file to make `bool`, `false`, and `true` visible.

If it doesn't (Microsoft's support for C99 is not good), a workaround is:

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

This doesn't *quite* match the semantics of C99's `bool` (actually `_Bool`) type, but it's probably close enough.

Incidentally, you don't need an if/else statement in your function:

```
static bool is_ascii_value_of_digit(char ascii_value) {
    return ascii_value >= '0' && ascii_value <= '9';
}
```

`bool` values are *values*, and they can be stored and returned from functions just like any other values.

Another guideline: Don't compare boolean values to `true` or `false`, just test them directly.  In a condition (such as in an `if` statement), any non-zero value is considered true, so this:

```
if (cond == true) ...
```

can fail if `cond` has non-zero value other than 1.  Just write:

```
if (cond) ...
```

or, to test whether it's false:

```
if (!cond) ...
```

Recommended reading: section 9 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).  (Further recommended reading: all the rest of the sections.)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c11.htm
i used it many years ago

```
#define True  1
#define False 0
typedef int boolean;

void main(void)
{
    boolean b;

    b=False;
    if(!b) printf("false");

}
```

In codepad output is false

http://codepad.org/iWKiFHFA

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`.  `b==False` is better written as `!b`.  Read section 9 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's "wrong", it's just not what you want most of the time. Sometimes you *have* to have main be of type void, for example many compilers for embedded systems require it.

Comment: @Demizey: Many compilers and libraries for embedded systems are not standards conforming and in the context of ANSI C they are wrong.

Comment: @oscode: False. In hosted implementations you need to return a value, but freestanding implementations, which are very common in embedded environments, have no such requirements and `void main()` is just fine.